# How to clear a GIT Repository

Tags: git, msysgit

In Tortoise SVN there is a [Repo-Browser](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html) where we can simply delete all files and add new files again.

**How can we do this in GIT?**

*repo is not hosted in GITHub and there is no interface apart of the repo url*

**Why?**

I created a local repo and pushed into the remote host, but realized after that was in the wrong directory, so, locally it's easy, just

```
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "New place commit;"

git remote add alias https://user@domain.com/reponame.git
git push alias master
```

but I get the error

```
To https://user@domain.com/reponame.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'user@domain.com/reponame.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Witch is fine as I'm pushing a new repo ... so I just want to clear the remote one in order to be able to push this new one ...

Comment: Probably you should see this thread:
[how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history

Comment: it's not exactly the same, I want to clear all and start from scratch, something that he doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `-f` flag:

```
git push -f alias master
```

It will force remote repository to overwrite `master` branch.

Comment: superb! there are so many flags that I was completely lost :)

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the `.git` directory at the top level of the repository. Then, in that same directory:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -am 'Initial commit'
```